# APT command line interface-like yes/no input?

Tags: python

Is there any short way to achieve what the APT (*Advanced Package Tool*) command line interface does in Python?

I mean, when the package manager prompts a yes/no question followed by `[Yes/no]`, the script accepts `YES/Y/yes/y` or <kbd>Enter</kbd> (defaults to `Yes` as hinted by the capital letter).

The only thing I find in the official docs is `input` and `raw_input`...

I know it's not that hard to emulate, but it's annoying to rewrite :|

Comment: In Python 3, `raw_input()` is called [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#input).

Answer (score 280, accepted):

As you mentioned, the easiest way is to use `raw_input()` (or simply `input()` for [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)). There is no built-in way to do this. From [Recipe 577058](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577058/):

```py
import sys


def query_yes_no(question, default="yes"):
    """Ask a yes/no question via raw_input() and return their answer.

    "question" is a string that is presented to the user.
    "default" is the presumed answer if the user just hits <Enter>.
            It must be "yes" (the default), "no" or None (meaning
            an answer is required of the user).

    The "answer" return value is True for "yes" or False for "no".
    """
    valid = {"yes": True, "y": True, "ye": True, "no": False, "n": False}
    if default is None:
        prompt = " [y/n] "
    elif default == "yes":
        prompt = " [Y/n] "
    elif default == "no":
        prompt = " [y/N] "
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid default answer: '%s'" % default)

    while True:
        sys.stdout.write(question + prompt)
        choice = input().lower()
        if default is not None and choice == "":
            return valid[default]
        elif choice in valid:
            return valid[choice]
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' " "(or 'y' or 'n').\n")
```

(For Python 2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`.)
Usage example:

```
>>> query_yes_no("Is cabbage yummier than cauliflower?")
Is cabbage yummier than cauliflower? [Y/n] oops
Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' (or 'y' or 'n').
Is cabbage yummier than cauliflower? [Y/n] [ENTER]
>>> True

>>> query_yes_no("Is cabbage yummier than cauliflower?", None)
Is cabbage yummier than cauliflower? [y/n] [ENTER]
Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' (or 'y' or 'n').
Is cabbage yummier than cauliflower? [y/n] y
>>> True
```

Comment: Actually, there is a function strtobool in the standart library: http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=distutils.util#distutils.util.strtobool

Comment: Just a remember: 

`raw_input()` is called `input()` in Python3

Answer (score 100):

I'd do it this way:

```
# raw_input returns the empty string for "enter"
yes = {'yes','y', 'ye', ''}
no = {'no','n'}

choice = raw_input().lower()
if choice in yes:
   return True
elif choice in no:
   return False
else:
   sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no'")
```

Comment: `raw_input()` is called `input()` in Python3

Answer (score 95):

You can use [click](http://click.pocoo.org/)'s `confirm` method.

```
import click

if click.confirm('Do you want to continue?', default=True):
    print('Do something')
```

This will print:

```
$ Do you want to continue? [Y/n]:
```

Should work for `Python 2/3` on Linux, Mac or Windows.

Docs: http://click.pocoo.org/5/prompts/#confirmation-prompts

Answer (score 54):

There is a function `strtobool` in Python's standard library: http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=distutils.util#distutils.util.strtobool

You can use it to check user's input and transform it to `True` or `False` value.

Comment: `f` probably stands for False, and `False == 0`, so I get the logic. Why the function would return an `int` instead of a `bool` is a mystery to me though.

Comment: @FrançoisLeblanc as to Why it is most common in Databases. If it is not explicitly `False` or `0` (Zero).  Anything, else that is evaluated using the bool function becomes true and will return: `1`.

Comment: @JayRizzo I get that, and they're [both functionally similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640674/differentiate-false-and-0) in most respects. But it means you can't use singleton comparison, i.e. `if strtobool(string) is False: do_stuff()`.

Answer (score 50):

A very simple (but not very sophisticated) way of doing this for a single choice would be:

```
msg = 'Shall I?'
shall = input("%s (y/N) " % msg).lower() == 'y'
```

You could also write a simple (slightly improved) function around this:

```
def yn_choice(message, default='y'):
    choices = 'Y/n' if default.lower() in ('y', 'yes') else 'y/N'
    choice = input("%s (%s) " % (message, choices))
    values = ('y', 'yes', '') if choices == 'Y/n' else ('y', 'yes')
    return choice.strip().lower() in values
```

Note: On Python 2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Love the first approach.  Short and easy.  I used something like `result = raw_input("message").lower() in ('y','yes')`

Answer (score 28):

as mentioned by @Alexander Artemenko, here's a simple solution using strtobool

```
from distutils.util import strtobool

def user_yes_no_query(question):
    sys.stdout.write('%s [y/n]\n' % question)
    while True:
        try:
            return strtobool(raw_input().lower())
        except ValueError:
            sys.stdout.write('Please respond with \'y\' or \'n\'.\n')

#usage

>>> user_yes_no_query('Do you like cheese?')
Do you like cheese? [y/n]
Only on tuesdays
Please respond with 'y' or 'n'.
ok
Please respond with 'y' or 'n'.
y
>>> True
```

Comment: just curious... why `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print` ?

Comment: Note that `strtobool()` does not (from my tests) require a `lower()`. This is not explicit in its documentation, however.

Answer (score 16):

I know this has been answered a bunch of ways and this may not answer OP's specific question (with the list of criteria) but this is what I did for the most common use case and it's far simpler than the other responses:

```
answer = input('Please indicate approval: [y/n]')
if not answer or answer[0].lower() != 'y':
    print('You did not indicate approval')
    exit(1)
```

Comment: this does not work with python 2 -- `raw_input` was renamed `input` in python 3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined

Answer (score 12):

You can also use [prompter](https://github.com/tylerdave/prompter).

Shamelessly taken from the README:

```
#pip install prompter

from prompter import yesno

>>> yesno('Really?')
Really? [Y/n]
True

>>> yesno('Really?')
Really? [Y/n] no
False

>>> yesno('Really?', default='no')
Really? [y/N]
True
```

Comment: Beware that the behaviour of prompter is pretty backwards when you're using it with "default='no'"; it will return True when you choose 'no' and False when you choose 'yes'.

Answer (score 7):

I modified fmark's answer to by python 2/3 compatible more pythonic.

See [ipython's utility module](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/aa586fd81940e557a1df54ecd0478f9d67dfb6b4/IPython/utils/io.py#L141-171) if you are interested in something with more error handling

```
# PY2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function
# You could use the six package for this
try:
    input_ = raw_input
except NameError:
    input_ = input

def query_yes_no(question, default=True):
    """Ask a yes/no question via standard input and return the answer.

    If invalid input is given, the user will be asked until
    they acutally give valid input.

    Args:
        question(str):
            A question that is presented to the user.
        default(bool|None):
            The default value when enter is pressed with no value.
            When None, there is no default value and the query
            will loop.
    Returns:
        A bool indicating whether user has entered yes or no.

    Side Effects:
        Blocks program execution until valid input(y/n) is given.
    """
    yes_list = ["yes", "y"]
    no_list = ["no", "n"]

    default_dict = {  # default => prompt default string
        None: "[y/n]",
        True: "[Y/n]",
        False: "[y/N]",
    }

    default_str = default_dict[default]
    prompt_str = "%s %s " % (question, default_str)

    while True:
        choice = input_(prompt_str).lower()

        if not choice and default is not None:
            return default
        if choice in yes_list:
            return True
        if choice in no_list:
            return False

        notification_str = "Please respond with 'y' or 'n'"
        print(notification_str)
```

Comment: Compatible with both Python 2 and 3, very readable. I ended up using this answer.

Answer (score 7):

For Python 3, I'm using this function:

```
def user_prompt(question: str) -> bool:
    """ Prompt the yes/no-*question* to the user. """
    from distutils.util import strtobool

    while True:
        user_input = input(question + " [y/n]: ")
        try:
            return bool(strtobool(user_input))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please use y/n or yes/no.\n")
```

The [`strtobool()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=distutils.util#distutils.util.strtobool) function converts a string into a bool. If the string cant be parsed it will raise a ValueError.

In Python 3 `raw_input()` has been renamed to [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

As Geoff said, strtobool actually returns 0 or 1, therefore the result has to be cast to bool.

---

This is the implementation of `strtobool`, if you want special words to be recognized as `true`, you can copy the code and add your own cases.

```py
def strtobool (val):
    """Convert a string representation of truth to true (1) or false (0).
    True values are 'y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', and '1'; false values
    are 'n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', and '0'.  Raises ValueError if
    'val' is anything else.
    """
    val = val.lower()
    if val in ('y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', '1'):
        return 1
    elif val in ('n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', '0'):
        return 0
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid truth value %r" % (val,))
```

Comment: And one minor thing that probably doesn't matter much in practice: `strtobool`, for some reason, returns 0 and 1, rather than `False` and `True`. So if you need `False` and `True`, be sure to call `bool(strtobool(user_input))`.

Answer (score 6):

on 2.7, is this too non-pythonic?

```
if raw_input('your prompt').lower()[0]=='y':
   your code here
else:
   alternate code here
```

it captures any variation of Yes at least.

Answer (score 4):

Doing the same with python 3.x, where `raw_input()` doesn't exist:

```
def ask(question, default = None):
    hasDefault = default is not None
    prompt = (question 
               + " [" + ["y", "Y"][hasDefault and default] + "/" 
               + ["n", "N"][hasDefault and not default] + "] ")

    while True:
        sys.stdout.write(prompt)
        choice = input().strip().lower()
        if choice == '':
            if default is not None:
                return default
        else:
            if "yes".startswith(choice):
                return True
            if "no".startswith(choice):
                return False

        sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' "
                             "(or 'y' or 'n').\n")
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. In more than one way actually. Currently trying to fix it, but I think this will look a lot like the accepted answer after I'm done.

Comment: I edited you anwser @pjm . Please consider reviewing it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the code below to be able to work with choices from the variable 'accepted' show here:

```
print( 'accepted: {}'.format(accepted) )
# accepted: {'yes': ['', 'Yes', 'yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y'], 'no': ['No', 'no', 'NO', 'n', 'N']}
```

Here is the code ..

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def makeChoi(yeh, neh):
    accept = {}
    # for w in words:
    accept['yes'] = [ '', yeh, yeh.lower(), yeh.upper(), yeh.lower()[0], yeh.upper()[0] ]
    accept['no'] = [ neh, neh.lower(), neh.upper(), neh.lower()[0], neh.upper()[0] ]
    return accept

accepted = makeChoi('Yes', 'No')

def doYeh():
    print('Yeh! Let\'s do it.')

def doNeh():
    print('Neh! Let\'s not do it.')

choi = None
while not choi:
    choi = input( 'Please choose: Y/n? ' )
    if choi in accepted['yes']:
        choi = True
        doYeh()
    elif choi in accepted['no']:
        choi = True
        doNeh()
    else:
        print('Your choice was "{}". Please use an accepted input value ..'.format(choi))
        print( accepted )
        choi = None
```

Answer (score 2):

As a programming noob, I found a bunch of the above answers overly complex, especially if the goal is to have a simple function that you can pass various yes/no questions to, forcing the user to select yes or no. After scouring this page and several others, and borrowing all of the various good ideas, I ended up with the following:

```
def yes_no(question_to_be_answered):
    while True:
        choice = input(question_to_be_answered).lower()
        if choice[:1] == 'y': 
            return True
        elif choice[:1] == 'n':
            return False
        else:
            print("Please respond with 'Yes' or 'No'\n")

#See it in Practice below 

musical_taste = yes_no('Do you like Pine Coladas?')
if musical_taste == True:
    print('and getting caught in the rain')
elif musical_taste == False:
    print('You clearly have no taste in music')
```

Comment: Shouldn't the argument be called "question" instead of "answer"?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
import sys

# cs = case sensitive
# ys = whatever you want to be "yes" - string or tuple of strings

#  prompt('promptString') == 1:               # only y
#  prompt('promptString',cs = 0) == 1:        # y or Y
#  prompt('promptString','Yes') == 1:         # only Yes
#  prompt('promptString',('y','yes')) == 1:   # only y or yes
#  prompt('promptString',('Y','Yes')) == 1:   # only Y or Yes
#  prompt('promptString',('y','yes'),0) == 1: # Yes, YES, yes, y, Y etc.

def prompt(ps,ys='y',cs=1):
    sys.stdout.write(ps)
    ii = raw_input()
    if cs == 0:
        ii = ii.lower()
    if type(ys) == tuple:
        for accept in ys:
            if cs == 0:
                accept = accept.lower()
            if ii == accept:
                return True
    else:
        if ii == ys:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def question(question, answers):
    acceptable = False
    while not acceptable:
        print(question + "specify '%s' or '%s'") % answers
        answer = raw_input()
        if answer.lower() == answers[0].lower() or answers[0].lower():
            print('Answer == %s') % answer
            acceptable = True
    return answer

raining = question("Is it raining today?", ("Y", "N"))
```

This is how I'd do it.

Output

```
Is it raining today? Specify 'Y' or 'N'
> Y
answer = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it, I simply wanted to abort if the user did not affirm the action.

```
import distutils

if unsafe_case:
    print('Proceed with potentially unsafe thing? [y/n]')
    while True:
        try:
            verify = distutils.util.strtobool(raw_input())
            if not verify:
                raise SystemExit  # Abort on user reject
            break
        except ValueError as err:
            print('Please enter \'yes\' or \'no\'')
            # Try again
    print('Continuing ...')
do_unsafe_thing()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def yes(prompt = 'Please enter Yes/No: '):
while True:
    try:
        i = raw_input(prompt)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return False
    if i.lower() in ('yes','y'): return True
    elif i.lower() in ('no','n'): return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer is expected yes or no, in the examples below, the first solution is to repeat the question using the function `while`, and the second solution is to use `recursion` - is the process of defining something in terms of itself.

```py
def yes_or_no(question):
    while "the answer is invalid":
        reply = str(input(question+' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
        if reply[:1] == 'y':
            return True
        if reply[:1] == 'n':
            return False

yes_or_no("Do you know who Novak Djokovic is?")
```

second solution:

```py
def yes_or_no(question):
    """Simple Yes/No Function."""
    prompt = f'{question} ? (y/n): '
    answer = input(prompt).strip().lower()
    if answer not in ['y', 'n']:
        print(f'{answer} is invalid, please try again...')
        return yes_or_no(question)
    if answer == 'y':
        return True
    return False

def main():
    """Run main function."""
    answer = yes_or_no("Do you know who Novak Djokovic is?")
    print(f'you answer was: {answer}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

One-liner with Python 3.8 and above:

```
while res:= input("When correct, press enter to continue...").lower() not in {'y','yes','Y','YES',''}: pass
```

Answer (score -1):

Python x.x

```
res = True
while res:
    res = input("Please confirm with y/yes...").lower(); res = res not in {'y','yes','Y','YES',''}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I used to do is...

```
question = 'Will the apple fall?'
print(question)
answer = int(input("Pls enter the answer: "
if answer == "y",
print('Well done')
print(answer)
```