# Python yes/no def

Tags: python, prompt

I'm using the example below:

[APT command line interface-like yes/no input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041986/python-command-line-yes-no-input)

I want to make it its own definition as outlined then call it upon demand, like this:

```
def log_manager():  
    question = "Do you wish to continue?"  
    choice = query_yes_no_quit(question, default="yes")  
        if choice == 'y':  
            print ("you entered y")  
        else:     
            print ("not working")
```

Regardless of what I input, "not working" is always printed. Any guidance would be really appreciated!

Comment: What is the return value, `choice`, from the `query_yes_no_quit()` function?  Please print that and **update** your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function returns True/False. So use `if choice:`

Btw, you could have easily found out the solution on your own by adding `print choice` ;)

Comment: Thanks for that! I sorted it out based on your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if choice:
    print("you entered y")
else:
    print("not working")
```

the function returns `True` / `False`, not `"y"` / `"n"`.