# Monkeypatching input causes attribute error during testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to monkeypatch in pytest the input function to simulate user input but I'm getting an attribute error.

I receive the same error when I use the mock.patch.object as well. But I'm able to readily monkeypatch the input when I'm in a regular Python environment, I only get this error in testing.[image]

What could be causing this issue?

**Edit**
Adding additional screenshot trying same thing using unittest.mock
[image: Unittestmockerror]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots but your actual code.

Answer (score 3):

`__builtins__` is an implementation detail. You shouldn't touch it. What you're looking for is either the `__builtin__` (no `s`) or `builtins` module, depending on whether you're on Python 2 or 3.

Judging by the details of the error you got, you're on Python 3, so you want `builtins`.

Comment: I'm on Python3 but I need to replace the input() function with one that returns a fake input. Trying to this without using a decorator or mock module http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161330/using-unittest-mock-to-patch-input-in-python-3

Comment: @canyon289 I'm confused. You provided a link that has two answers using a decorator and uses mock. And if you are looking for input to return a fake input, you are mocking input's functionality. So, I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: One parts of my program takes a user input and returns a value. I'm trying to test using pytest and part of that test is having the input function return a value. To automate that test I'm trying to monkeypatch/mock the regular input function with one that will return a string set in the test. I get this same error whether I use the mock module or the pytest monkeypatch function