# Python - unittest, mock, patch, input

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, return, patch

so i've got a problem with my code.
File 1:

```
class Abc(object):
...
def function1(self):
 #do something
def function2(self):
 x = input()
 return x+1
```

and now i'm trying to test function 2 so i wrote a test for it and i don't know what i am doing wrong:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import unittest
from file1 import *

class TestBackend(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_mode_first(self):
        self.assertEqual(Abc().funcion1(), 30)

    @patch('funcion2.input', create=True)
    def test_mode_second(self, mocked_input):
        mocked_input.side_effect = ["QWE"]
        result = Abc().funcion2()
        self.assertEqual(result, 10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

i get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'function2'
so what i am doing wrong in here?

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using unittest.mock to patch input() in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161330/using-unittest-mock-to-patch-input-in-python-3)

Comment: there is ImportError in your link and i get ModuleNotFoundError: no module named function2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `ModuleNotFoundError` because `funcion2` is not a module. [`patch doc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) is clear about this:

> target should be a string in the form 'package.module.ClassName'. The
>   target is imported and the specified object replaced with the new
>   object, so the target must be importable from the environment you are
>   calling patch() from. The target is imported when the decorated
>   function is executed, not at decoration time.

This works for me when executed with `python3 -m unittest discover` from the directory the files are in.

BTW you have a couple of typos in your example, e.g. `Abc().funcion2()`, note the missing `t` in `funcion2`.

Also, try not to use `from … import *`: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/from_module_import_all_used.html#using-wildcard-imports-from-import

```
# file1.py
class Abc(object):
    def function1(self):
        return 30

    def function2(self):
        x = input()
        return x + "1"
```

```
# test_file1.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from file1 import Abc


class TestBackend(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_mode_first(self):
        self.assertEqual(Abc().function1(), 30)

    @patch('builtins.input')
    def test_mode_second(self, mocked_input):
        mocked_input.return_value = "QWE"

        result = Abc().function2()
        self.assertEqual(result, "QWE1")
```