# Python feed data to input() method but with files (not terminal)

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, io

So I want to write a script to run tests on my codes.

In my python file, I need to take inputs with the `input()` method, type the input from the terminal, and my program then returns the output to the terminal.

But then I have a folder with testing files, file names like `xx.in` and sample output for them `xx.out`.

In my main program, I need to read inputs with `input()` because it is a rule for my assignments. But in my testing scripts, can I read a file, store the data of that file in a buffer (or a stack?), then feed it to my program (line by line)?

Also, is there a way to write the output from `print()` which prints to the terminal, but can store it in a file?

At last, the inputs are multi-line, and my program take each line with one `input()` using a loop, and maybe `print()` one line of results before it goes to next iteration and read `input()` again, is there anything I need to take care about that part? Like will the line of input() be included into my output? I don't want it to happen.

Comment: Look at the `mock` module and the `patch` function.  It sounds like you want to `patch` the `input` and `print` functions in your test to map terminal I/O to files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using unittest.mock to patch input() in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161330/using-unittest-mock-to-patch-input-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without mock.

main module like

```
def main():
    # here your code
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

testing script into directory with main module

```
from os import listdir, path
import sys
from main import main

def test_all_files(inpdir, outdir):
    files = [f[:-3] for f in listdir(inpdir) if f[-3:] == '.in' and path.isfile(f'{inpdir}\\{f}')]
    for name in files:
        with open(f'{inpdir}\\{name}.in') as inp, open(f'{outdir}\\{name}.out', 'w') as out:
            sys.stdin, sys.stdout = inp, out
            main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # here you can write code for read path of folder with test files
    workdir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
    test_all_files(workdir, workdir)
```

But if you want to work with testing more, better solution read information about autotest systems like `mock`