# Using input to have options 3.4.3

Tags: python

Is it possible to use python and have a set list of options to choose from?

For example when asked for input let you choose "Yes" "No" or "Maybe"

Comment: Does that mean Python 3.4.3?

Comment: @localhost yep. I brainfarted and put it at the end at the last minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that a bit of searching would've done you some good on this one.

See answer to extremely similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041990/5298696

Adding a "Maybe" option would be a trivial edit, provide an update if you need assistance with that.

Comment: Oops.. Thanks a ton! I wasn't really sure what to search for. Appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help out. Definitely do give an update if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
def yesno_to_bool(s):
    s = s.lower()
    if s == "yes":
        return True
    elif s == "no":
        return False
```

Which works like this:

```
>>> yesno_to_bool("yes")
True
>>> yesno_to_bool("no")
False
>>> yesno_to_bool("Maybe")
None
```