# yesno_prompt( issue

Tags: python, smtp, sendmail

My code is this:

```
highpri = yesno_prompt(
    ["1"], "Flag this message/s as high priority? [yes|no]")
if not "YES" in highpri:
    prioflag1 = ""
    prioflag2 = ""
else:
    prioflag1 = ' 1 (Highest)'
    prioflag2 = ' High'
```

But when I run it, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mailerproj.py", line 138, in <module>
    highpri = yesno_prompt(
NameError: name 'yesno_prompt' is not defined
```

So I tried:

```
highpri = input(
```

But it gives issue this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mailerproj.py", line 139, in <module>
    ["1"], "Flag this message/s as high priority? [yes|no]")
TypeError: [raw_]input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

So in this case, is input the best but structured wrong or is yes/no prompt right but structured wrong?

Comment: No idea what `yesno_prompt` is supposed to be, or what its arguments represent. `input` (or `raw_input`, in Python 2) takes only one argument, the prompt string `"Flag this message ... "`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041986/python-command-line-yes-no-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how `input()` works in Python 3.

First, the `input()` function in Python 3 is equivalent to `raw_input()` in Python 2. Your error shows that you are using Python 2.

So let's read the error message you got:

We know what line the error is on:

```
  File "mailerproj.py", line 139, in <module>
```

And it shows us the line:

```
    ["1"], "Flag this message/s as high priority? [yes|no]")
```

And then it explains the issue:

```
TypeError: [raw_]input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

This means you've given `input()` the wrong arguments - you've given it two `["1"]` and `"Flag this message/s as high priority? [yes|no]"` and it expects one.

Here is the python help on `raw_input`:

Help on built-in function raw_input in module **builtin**:

```
raw_input(...)
    raw_input([prompt]) -> string

    Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped. If the
    user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError. On Unix,
    GNU readline is used if enabled. The prompt string, if given, is printed
    without a trailing newline before reading.
```

So you need to give it one argument as input. This can be a string (e.g. `"Hello"`) an integer (e.g. `125`),  a float (e.g. `3.14`), a list, a tuple, a boolean and others. It returns a string into the variable.

You need your code to look more like this:

```
highpri = raw_input("[1] Flag this message as high priority? [yes|no] > ")
highpri = highpri.upper()  # Make the input uppercase for the if
if highpri != 'YES':       # If it is not yes, remove the flags.
    prioflag1 = ''
    prioflag2 = ''
else:                      # If the input is yes, set the flags.
    prioflag1 = '1 (Highest)'
    prioflag2 = 'High'
```

Comment: That fixed my issue. I didn't realize it was taking [1] as it's own argument. Just removing `[1],` fixed the error and runs the script in terminal. Thanks for the breakdown!